# Using T-SQL DATEFROMPARTS() in C# Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have the following T-SQL query which I'm trying to convert into C# code:

```sql
SELECT 
    *, DATEFROMPARTS(Jaar, Maand, 1) 
FROM 
    EAN_Budget_Meetdata_Factuur
WHERE
    EID = 1 AND
    Bron = 'B' AND
    DATEFROMPARTS(Jaar, Maand, 1)  BETWEEN '20161101' AND '20170101'
```

The table contains a column Year and Month, and I'm querying the table based on two known DateTimes (a period).

The query is meant to retrieve the table rows that apply to this period based on the years and months between the two DateTimes.

What is the best way to convert this query into C#? I've so far come up with the following, without success:

```
var query = from b in CT2.EAN_Budget_Meetdata_Factuur
            let JaarTest = b.Jaar + "-" + b.Maand + "-01"
            where 
                b.EID == 1 &&
                b.Bron == "B" &&
                JaarTest == "something"
                select new
                {
                    JaarTest = b.Jaar + "-" + b.Maand + "-01"
                };
```

Comment: Will the query always cover a 3 month period?

Comment: Why not use DateTime's constructor that takes year, month, and day?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No, this differs every time. Sometimes it's a month, sometimes 3 months, sometimes more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `DATEFROMPARTS` on table columns you've already lost any opportunity for indexes to be useful on the database side - so I'd instead recommend working in total months.<sup>1</sup>

`(year * 12) + months` is a simple calculation that you can perform both with the table columns and whatever start/end points you want to query for and you then can perform simple int range checks.

---

<sup>1</sup>In the alternative, if you hadn't realised that this was going to deny you any indexing ability, you might want to consider adding a *computed column* on which you apply an index - in which case the column definition would use the function (either the total months calculation I give here or the original `DATEFROMPARTS` one) and you'd then query that column easily.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var query = EAN_Budget_Meetdata_Factuur.factuurs
                    .Where(x => (x.eid == 1) && (x.bron == "B") && (x.date >= new DateTime(2016, 11, 1)) && (x.date <= new DateTime(2017, 1, 1)))
                    .Select(x => new { eid = x.eid, bron = x.bron, date = x.date })
                    .ToList();
        }
    }
    public class EAN_Budget_Meetdata_Factuur
    {
        public static List<EAN_Budget_Meetdata_Factuur> factuurs = new List<EAN_Budget_Meetdata_Factuur>();

        public int eid { get; set; }
        public string bron { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
    }
```